# log4j2 works on Mac but not on Windows

Tags: java, spring-boot, log4j2

I have log4j2 working in Springboot working fine on the Mac. The log4j.properties file is in the /src/main/resources folder.

On the mac, logs work fine. Yet, on Windows, the same SpringBoot Tomcat application throws JNDI errors for the logger.

```
""2024-02-18 06:56:52 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate - Looking up JNDI object with name [java:comp/env/log4j2.ContextData]
""2024-02-18 06:56:52 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate - Looking up JNDI object with name [java:comp/env/AsyncLogger.ThreadNameStrategy]
""2024-02-18 06:56:52 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.jndi.JndiLocatorDelegate - Converted JNDI name [java:comp/env/AsyncLogger.ThreadNameStrategy] not found - trying original name [AsyncLogger.ThreadNameStrategy]. javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [AsyncLogger.ThreadNameStrategy] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [AsyncLogger.ThreadNameStrategy].
""2024-02-18 06:56:52 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate - Looking up JNDI object with name [AsyncLogger.ThreadNameStrategy]
""2024-02-18 06:56:52 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.jndi.JndiPropertySource - JNDI lookup for name [AsyncLogger.ThreadNameStrategy] threw NamingException with message: Name [AsyncLogger.ThreadNameStrategy] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [AsyncLogger.ThreadNameStrategy].. Returning null.
""2024-02-18 06:56:52 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate - Looking up JNDI object with name [java:comp/env/log4j2.debug]
""2024-02-18 06:56:52 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.jndi.JndiLocatorDelegate - Converted JNDI name [java:comp/env/log4j2.debug] not found - trying original name [log4j2.debug]. javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [log4j2.debug] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [log4j2.debug].
""2024-02-18 06:56:52 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate - Looking up JNDI object with name [log4j2.debug]
""2024-02-18 06:56:52 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.jndi.JndiPropertySource - JNDI lookup for name [log4j2.debug] threw NamingException with message: Name [log4j2.debug] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [log4j2.debug].. Returning null.
""2024-02-18 06:56:52 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate - Looking up JNDI object with name [java:comp/env/log4j.Clock]
""2024-02-18 06:56:52 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.jndi.JndiLocatorDelegate - Converted JNDI name [java:comp/env/log4j.Clock] not found - trying original name [log4j.Clock]. javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [log4j.Clock] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [log4j.Clock].
""2024-02-18 06:56:52 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate - Looking up JNDI object with name [log4j.Clock]
""2024-02-18 06:56:52 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.jndi.JndiPropertySource - JNDI lookup for name [log4j.Clock] threw NamingException with message: Name [log4j.Clock] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [log4j.Clock].. Returning null.
""2024-02-18 06:56:52 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate - Looking up JNDI object with name [java:comp/env/log4j2.debug]
""2024-02-18 06:56:52 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.jndi.JndiLocatorDelegate - Converted JNDI name [java:comp/env/log4j2.debug] not found - trying original name [log4j2.debug]. javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [log4j2.debug] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [log4j2.debug].
""2024-02-18 06:56:52 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate - Looking up JNDI object with name [log4j2.debug]]
```

In the log4j2.properties file, I read the system environment variable for the log directory like this:

property.basePath = ${sys:LOG_DIR}

Again, this approach works fine on the Mac. It also creates the log file itself on Windows (so it seems it's getting the right log directory from the environment variable on Windows), but then on Windows it fills the log with hundreds of JNDI errors like I posted above.

I've also tried a hard-coded full path to the log directory on Windows, but I get the same hundreds of JNDI errors in the Windows SpringBoot log4j2 log.

I've also tried moving the log4j2.properties file to /src folder in the app as someone on SO suggested. This idea unfortunately didn't work.

How can this work perfectly on the Mac but not at all on Windows using the exact Tomcat and WAR file?

What do I need to try next?

Thanks,

Comment: What exactly is not working on Windows? You say that the log file is created on both systems and on Windows you see log events being written to that file. If you use the same configuration file on both systems, I would say that you have a problem on Mac.

Comment: On Windows I get tons of startup problem reports (JNDI errors as posted above). These don't appear to be any issues but on the Mac the log appears "normal" -- just log entries. I don't understand how logging itself works on both platforms, but on Windows, I get about 350KB of garbage log entries I can't stop. Sorry if I didn't make that clear. :)

Comment: Please add your configuration file to the question. The most probably cause is that you set the level of the `org.springframework` logger to `DEBUG` in one of the automatically detected config files (cf. [documentation](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#AutomaticConfiguration) for a list).

Comment: Thank you for your help! Yes, the problem turned out to be that in "application.properties", where apparently the default logger is configured (not the root logger), I had "DEBUG" and in the log4j2.properties file I had "INFO". Once I changed the value in application.properties to "INFO", everything is working as expected. I now see what you mean about the Mac missing something. :) Thanks very much for your kind replies.

Comment: One other question. On the Mac, I can read an environment variable in log4j2.properties like this: ${sys:LOG_DIR}, but this doesn't work on Windows. Is there a different syntax needed so it works for both platforms or is it just best to hard-code the path? Thanks.

Comment: Can you write an answer with the solution?
Regarding the `${sys:...}`, it is for Java system properties, not for OS environment variables. For environment variables use `${env:...}`.

Comment: Thank you. The "env" works on Windows but not on Mac! So annoying these OS differences. I guess since the client uses Windows, I'll just need to modify the log4j.properties file (property.basePath) for local log usage. How should I write up the solution to the logging problem as you suggested?  Do I use "Answer your question" button at the bottom of the page? I want to make sure I do this correctly so it's the most helpful to others.

Comment: Yes, "Answer your question" is the right way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

The issue I had with all the unwanted log messages on Windows appeared to be that in application.properties, I had the log level set to DEBUG while in the log4j2.properties file I also had it set to DEBUG.

Once I changed DEBUG to INFO in the log4j2.properties file, the problems went away.

Since this issue did not occur the same way on the Mac (no extra log messages entered on start), it was confusing to figure out.

My thanks to Piotr for his excellent help.